# Login failure for user for an application in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm developing  an application in asp.net and encountered the following problem:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connString = "Data Source = JOHN-4E29FADEE; database=PEOPLE;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();
        Response.Write("Succes");
        SqlCommand comanda = new SqlCommand();
        comanda.Connection = conn;
        comanda.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        comanda.CommandText = "Select PERSON_ID,FIRST_NAME,FATHER_INITIALS, LAST_NAME, BIRTHDATE,CNP,MOTHER_CNP,FATHER_CNP from PERSON order by FIRST_NAME"; 
        SqlDataReader dr = comanda.ExecuteReader();
        GridView4.DataSource = dr;
        GridView4.DataBind();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException exc)
    {
        Response.Write("Connection Error! " + exc.Message);
    }
}
```

When I launch the application I get `Connection Error! Login failed for user`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to provide username and password of sqlserver database in connection string.

Comment: I connect to sql server with windows authentication and i don't remember to set a username and a password for SQL Server authentication when i installed SQL Server 2008. What should I do in this case?

Comment: you have to use your windows credentials. user and password you provide to login

Comment: I provide the credentials but the only change is that Connection Error! Login failed for user John.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
connetionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=Databasename;
  User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
```

Comment: I connect to sql server with windows authentication

Comment: You should be try this :-                                         
connectionString="Initial Catalog=MyDb;Data Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Answer (score 0):

try SqlConnectionStringBuilder ... much easier to assign some values to properties than to create a cryptic connection string from scratch